# How to pass '--web.enable-admin-api' flag to in victoriametrics

Tags: curl, prometheus, victoriametrics

To enable the delete operation we may need to enable the `--web.enable-admin-api'`flag so how we can enable it . I am currently using non docker single node cluster version and trying to run below curl command

```
curl -X DELETE -g 'http://localhost:8481/api/v1/0/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={foo.bar.baz="bar"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [delete API in VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#how-to-delete-time-series) works out of the box. There is no need in enabling it.

It looks like your command contains invalid port and path to `delete API` in single-node VictoriaMetrics. Try the following command according to [docs](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#how-to-delete-time-series):

```
curl -g 'http://localhost:8428/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]={foo.bar.baz="bar"}'
```

Note that the `match[]` arg must be properly encoded with [url encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Otherwise it may be improperly transferred to VictoriaMetrics.